# Laravel PUT not receiving parameters/request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.1 and I have encountered a strange issue. I am unable to receive parameter with PUT method.

**Tool**:

> POSTMAN (extension for chrome)

**My Route**

```
Route::put('testing_put',function(Request $r){
    print_r($r);
});
```

**Output**

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request Object ( )
```

[image]

Comment: Could you try run `dd($r->all())`?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin

It gives

FatalThrowableError in routes.php line 3:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::get()

Comment: @cheese5505
it gives following error
FatalThrowableError in api_routes.php line 3:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()

Comment: @AliZain answered below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple!

Change POSTMAN from **form-data** to **x-form-www-urlencoded**

[image: Change this in POSTMAN and then send]

Answer (score 1):

You are type-hinting the Illuminate Facade. Try changing `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` to `use Illuminate\Http\Request`.